# using substitution wrongly

Tags: calculus, integration

Solving integral, first way:

$$\int \frac{du}{u^2-9}=-\int \frac{du}{9-u^2}$$
$$u={3\sin v}$$
$$du=3\cos vdv$$
$$-\int \frac{3\cos vdv }{9-9\sin^{2}v}=-\frac 13\int\frac{dv}{\cos v}=-\frac 13\ln\left(\sec v+\tan v\right)=-\frac13 \ln \frac {\frac u3}{\sqrt{1-\frac{u^2}{9}}}$$
$$-\frac13 \ln \frac{u}{\sqrt{9-u^2}}=-\frac16 \ln \frac {u^2}{9-u^2}=\frac16 \ln \frac{9-u^2}{u^2}$$

second way:
$$\int \frac{du}{u^2-9}=\frac 16\int \frac{du}{u-3}-\frac16 \int \frac{du}{u+3}=\frac16 \ln \frac {u-3}{u+3}$$

what's wrong with first way?

Thanks all. $1$ from $\sec$ is missed, must be $1+\frac u3$

Comment: $ln(sec v + tan v) \neq ln(sec v) + ln(tan v)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$-\dfrac 13 \ln|\sec v + \tan v|$ $ = -\dfrac 13 \ln \left| \dfrac{1+\sin v}{\cos v} \right| \\ = -\dfrac 13 \ln \left|\dfrac{3+u}{\sqrt{9-u^2}}\right| \\ = - \dfrac 16 \ln \left|\dfrac{(3+u)^2}{(3-u)(3+u)}\right| \\ = \dfrac 16 \ln\left|\dfrac{3-u}{3+u}\right|$

Answer (score 0):

The first term should be
$$
\begin{align}
-\frac 13\ln\left|\sec v+\tan v\right|+C&=-\frac 13\ln\left|\frac{3}{\sqrt{9-u^2}}+\frac{u}{\sqrt{9-u^2}}\right|+C\\
&=-\frac 13\ln\left|\frac{3+u}{\sqrt{9-u^2}}\right|+C\\
&=-\frac 13\ln\left|\sqrt{\frac{(3+u)(3+u)}{(3-u)(3+u)}}\right|+C\\
&=\frac 16\ln\left|\frac{3-u}{3+u}\right|+C.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

As Grid commented, before any simplification
$$\ln\left(\sec v+\tan v\right)=\log \left(\frac{u}{3 \sqrt{1-\frac{u^2}{9}}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{u^2}{9}}}\right)$$

Comment: I think v on the right side should be u

Comment: @NateEldredge. You are correct. I edit. Thanks.